# (node:72332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to serialize arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, vuex, vuex-modules

Hello I am new to the community and I had a question about an error I received.

I am also new to Vue.js, Vuex and electron, but after updating my MacOS computer to 10.15, I have been unable to build my vue electron application properly.

I am hit with an error of:

```
(node:72332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to serialize arguments
at WebContents._.send (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:157:2252)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex-electron/dist/shared-mutations.js?:1:1508)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at a.c (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex-electron/dist/shared-mutations.js?:1:1483)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex-electron/dist/shared-mutations.js?:1:2409)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js?:477:38)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Store.commit (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js?:477:6)
at boundCommit (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js?:414:19)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/vuex-rest-api/dist/Store.js?:174:33)
```

(node:72332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:72332) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

It seems to be a dependency issue with either Vuex-electron or Vuex-rest-api, but I am unsure as to what it means or how to handle it.

I have attempted:

deleting node_modules and package.lock.json and re-installing them using "npm install", but no success

I've also attempted to remove the createSharedMutations() method imported from "Vuex-electron" and the application shows the data retrieved from the API, however the state becomes unsharable in other classes.

Any help is appreciated, thank you